# vue2 composition api beforeRouteUpdate updating after the route changes

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have this route:

```
{
  path: "/categories/:categorySlug",
  name: "product-list",
  meta: {
    title: "Categories",
  },
},
```

When the component first loads, it pulls in the category and any products related to it. The problem is when I change the category slug, for some reason the category updates fine, but the products do not.
I decided to add a **beforeRouteUpdate** to force the products to change and I set it up like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "ProductList",
  components: { Brands, Chooser, Products },
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const searchTerm = computed(() => {
      return instance.proxy.$route.params.searchTerm;
    });

    const {
      brands,
      brandError,
      brandFacets,
      brandsLoading,
      brandsHasMoreResults,
      brandsItemsToShow,
      brandsQuery,
      brandsTotal,
      brandsFetchMore,
    } = useSearchBrands(searchTerm, 12, [], true);
    const {
      category,
      categoryError,
      categoryLoading,
      products,
      productError,
      productFacets,
      productsLoading,
      productsHasMoreResults,
      productsItemsToShow,
      productsQuery,
      productsTotal,
      productsFetchMore,
    } = useListProducts(instance);

    return {
      brands,
      brandError,
      brandFacets,
      brandsLoading,
      brandsHasMoreResults,
      brandsItemsToShow,
      brandsQuery,
      brandsTotal,
      category,
      categoryError,
      categoryLoading,
      products,
      productError,
      productFacets,
      productsLoading,
      productsHasMoreResults,
      productsItemsToShow,
      productsQuery,
      productsTotal,
      brandsFetchMore,
      productsFetchMore,
    };
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    console.log(to);
    this.productsQuery.refetch();
    next();
  },
});
```

At first glance it didn't look like anything happened, because if I changed route it still showed the same products as the first load. But if I change again, I noticed that it now displayed the products from the previous route change:

[image]

And if I change route from **ovens** to **coffee-machines** it will show the ovens.
I cant use **beforeRouteEnter** because I don't have access to **this** and using **beforeRouteLeave** doesn't update the component at all, even though in my logs, I can see the request is changing.

So, to summarise, when I change route using **beforeRouteUpdate** I can see in my logs that the request changes to the correct category and I can see the correct products returned, but I don't see the results in the component until I change route again (with the same component).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

---

**Update**
I have been asked to display the code for my product list. I use vue apollo and I have two generic functions, the first is **useGraphQuery** which looks like this:

```
import { ref } from "vue-demi";

import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";

export function useGraphQuery(params, gql, pathFn, clientId = "apiClient") {
  if (!params?.value)
    return {
      response: ref(undefined),
      loading: ref(false),
      error: ref(undefined),
      query: ref(undefined),
    };

  // TODO: figure our a way to skip the call if the parameters are null

  const { result, loading, error, query, fetchMore } = useQuery(gql, params, {
    clientId,
    //enabled: !!params?.value,
  });
  const response = useResult(result, null, pathFn);

  return { response, loading, error, query, fetchMore };
}
```

All my graphql queries use this.
Then for searches (i.e. the product search), uses another function called **useGraphSearch**:

```
import { computed } from "@vue/composition-api";

import { useGraphQuery } from "./graph-query";

export function useGraphSearch(params, gql, pathFn) {
  const { response, loading, error, query, fetchMore } = useGraphQuery(
    params,
    gql,
    pathFn
  );

  const items = computed(() => {
    if (!response.value) return [];
    return response.value.items;
  });

  const facets = computed(() => {
    if (!response.value) return [];
    return response.value.facets;
  });

  const total = computed(() => {
    if (!response.value) return 0;
    return response.value.total;
  });

  const hasMoreResults = computed(() => {
    if (!response.value) return false;
    return response.value.hasMoreResults;
  });

  const itemsToShow = computed(() => params.value.search.itemsToShow);

  const more = () => {
    useGetMore(params.value, fetchMore);
  };

  return {
    error,
    facets,
    hasMoreResults,
    items,
    itemsToShow,
    loading,
    query,
    total,
    more,
  };
}

function useGetMore(params, fetchMore) {
  params.search.page++;

  fetchMore({
    variables: params,
  });
}
```

On the route I mentioned before, there are 3 queries running. One of them seems to work without doing anything. that is the **useGetCategory** which looks like this:

```
import { computed } from "@vue/composition-api";

import * as getCategoryBySlug from "@graphql/api/query.category.gql";

import { useGraphQuery } from "./graph-query";

export function useGetCategory(instance) {
  const params = computed(() => {
    const route = instance.proxy.$route;
    const slug = route.params.categorySlug;
    if (!slug) return;
    return { slug };
  });

  const { response, error, loading } = useGraphQuery(
    params,
    getCategoryBySlug,
    (data) => data.categoryBySlug
  );

  return { category: response, categoryError: error, categoryLoading: loading };
}
```

This updates regardless whether I called **beforeRouteUpdate** or not.
The second one is the **useListProducts** which looks like this:

```
import { ComponentInternalInstance } from "@vue/composition-api";

import { useSearchCategoryProducts } from "@logic/search-products";
import { useTrackProductImpressions } from "@logic/track-product-impressions";
import { useTrackProductClick } from "@/_shared/logic/track-product-click";

export function useListProducts(instance: ComponentInternalInstance) {
  const {
    products,
    productError,
    productFacets,
    productsLoading,
    productsHasMoreResults,
    productsItemsToShow,
    productsQuery,
    productsTotal,
    productsFetchMore,
  } = useSearchCategoryProducts(instance);

  return {
    products,
    productError,
    productFacets,
    productsLoading,
    productsHasMoreResults,
    productsItemsToShow,
    productsQuery,
    productsTotal,
    productsFetchMore,
  };
}
```

as you can see here, this calls **useSearchCategoryProducts** which is just used to create the parameters and looks like this:

```
export function useSearchCategoryProducts(
  instance: ComponentInternalInstance,
  orderBy = [{ key: "InVenue", value: "desc" }]
) {
  const params = computed(() => {
    const slug = instance.proxy.$route.params.categorySlug;
    if (!slug) return;
    const filters = createFilters("CategorySlug", [slug]);
    const request = createRequest(defaultParameters, 1, filters, orderBy);
    return { search: request };
  });

  return queryProducts(params);
}

function queryProducts(params) {
  console.log(params);
  const {
    error,
    facets,
    hasMoreResults,
    items,
    itemsToShow,
    loading,
    query,
    total,
    more,
  } = useGraphSearch(params, searchProducts, (data) => data.searchProducts);
  return {
    products: items,
    productError: error,
    productsLoading: loading,
    productFacets: facets,
    productsHasMoreResults: hasMoreResults,
    productsItemsToShow: itemsToShow,
    productsTotal: total,
    productsQuery: query,
    productsFetchMore: more,
  };
}
```

You can see the **console.log** in the private function **queryProducts** which I can see that the params are updating.
I know this is a lot to take in, but I have created the **useGraphQuery** and **useGraphSearch** so I can ensure that every query I create is the same and should work in the same way. The reason **useGetCategory** and **useListProducts** don't work in the same way (i.e. the category changes when the route does, but the product list doesn't) is beyond me and it is the reason I am trying to implement **beforeRouteUpdate** at all.

The code for the setup looks like this btw:

```
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import Brands from "@components/brands/brands.component.vue";
import Chooser from "@components/chooser/chooser.component.vue";
import Products from "@components/products/products.component.vue";
import { useListProducts } from "./list-products";
import { useSearchBrands } from "@logic/search-brands";
import { useGetCategory } from "@logic/get-category";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "ProductList",
  components: { Brands, Chooser, Products },
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const searchTerm = computed(() => {
      return instance.proxy.$route.params.categorySlug;
    });

    const { category, categoryError, categoryLoading } =
      useGetCategory(instance);

    const {
      brands,
      brandError,
      brandFacets,
      brandsLoading,
      brandsHasMoreResults,
      brandsItemsToShow,
      brandsQuery,
      brandsTotal,
      brandsFetchMore,
    } = useSearchBrands(searchTerm, 12, [], true);
    const {
      products,
      productError,
      productFacets,
      productsLoading,
      productsHasMoreResults,
      productsItemsToShow,
      productsQuery,
      productsTotal,
      productsFetchMore,
    } = useListProducts(instance);

    return {
      brands,
      brandError,
      brandFacets,
      brandsLoading,
      brandsHasMoreResults,
      brandsItemsToShow,
      brandsQuery,
      brandsTotal,
      category,
      categoryError,
      categoryLoading,
      products,
      productError,
      productFacets,
      productsLoading,
      productsHasMoreResults,
      productsItemsToShow,
      productsQuery,
      productsTotal,
      brandsFetchMore,
      productsFetchMore,
    };
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    console.log(to);
    this.brandsQuery.refetch();
    this.productsQuery.refetch();
    next();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix this. It was down to my cache policy.
I had been doing this:

```
const typePolicy = {
  keyArgs: ["search", ["page", "skip"]],
  // Concatenate the incoming list items with
  // the existing list items.
  merge(existing: any = {}, incoming: any) {
    const items = (existing.items ? existing.items : []).concat(incoming.items);
    const item = { ...existing, ...incoming };
    item.items = items;
    return item;
  },
};

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        searchCategories: typePolicy,
        searchBrands: typePolicy,
        searchPages: typePolicy,
        searchProducts: typePolicy,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

So that my paginated results were always appended to my current list, but for some reason that was causing an issue. When I swapped to this:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
```

My issues were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You’re not using `to` for anything in the route update handler. If your loading code depends on the route it will have the previous information since the event happens *before* it is updated.

You’ll need to give the information about the `to` route to the code that is doing the loading, or use an after event.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? the "to" route has the parameters already in it as it's changing route and the **refetch** method uses that parameter to get the data. And what do you mean about an after event? is that different to **beforeRouteLeave**?

Comment: @r3plica How does it use it? You call that function with zero arguments. Where will it get `to`? Include all necessary code

Comment: in the setup code I create a params computed property which takes in the categorySlug. The refetch method uses that computed property and I can see that the values are correct

Comment: @r3plica So could you include that code then? It’s impossible to say what is wrong with code we can’t see and values we can’t verify

Comment: Yes, but I will have to warn you, it's vue apollo and any question I have asked so far seems to stump people :(

Comment: updated with the code, let me know if you have any questions :)